# An easier way to do an OR statement

Tags: vb.net

I have an if statement with a lot of or statements because there are a lot of possible inputs. Is there an easier way to do or statements than:

```
If arrValue(strLength - i) = "0" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "1" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "2" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "3" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "4" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "5" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "6" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "7" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "8" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "9" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "a" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "b" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "c" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "d" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "e" Or arrValue(strLength - i) = "f" Then
```

Like if I could do:

```
If arrValue(strLength - i) = "0" Or "1" Or "2" Or "3" Or "4" Or "5" Or "6" Or "7" Or "8" Or "9" Or "a" Or "b" Or "c" Or "d" Or "e" Or "f" Then
```

that would save me a lot of time and space. So is there a more condensed way to use the OR logical operator?

Comment: 0-f?  Hex values by any change?

Comment: Well Mark, then do this. Store your 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,6 & 7 in an array (say M). Assign your arrValue(strLength - i) to a variable (Say X) . Check if X exists in M . Problem solved.

Comment: BTW, what are you really trying to do?  Are you just trying to see if a string is a hexadecimal value?

Comment: @MatthewWhited I'm creating a data conversion calculator that can go from any data to any other data type. It supports binary, hexadecimal, octal, and decimal. I'm sure it already exists, but I couldn't find one and decided it would be good practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A case statement might be slightly less 'busy':

```
SELECT CASE arrValue(strLength - i)

   CASE "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
    'Do something
   CASE "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
    'Do something

END SELECT
```

Comment: All the characters trigger the same action. I only actually need two cases.

Comment: Or use the VB6 Select Case *To* feature to specify a range, like this *Case "1" To "9"*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
    string pattern = "[0-9a-z]";
    string valid = "a";
    string notValid = "?";

    var reg = new Regex(pattern);
    if (reg.IsMatch(valid))
    {
        ...
    }
```

It's c#, but with that [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx#Y633) you should be able to translate it.

If it's always just a char, you can also take that char, cast it to an integer, and then compare it to the range of `((int)'0', (int)'9')` and `((int)'a', (int)'z')`. That was my solution, when I've not known regular expressions :)

Comment: Okay, I provided everything you'll need.

Comment: As the OP tagged VB.NET only could you be so kind as to translate it for them?

Answer (score 2):

Lets see the full block of code. I'm sure there's a better way of doing what you want if we could see context.

Assign arrValue(strLength - i) to a variable to shorten things.

```
Dim s As String  = arrValue(strLength - i)
Dim possibleValues As String = "0123456789ABCDEF"
For Each Char c In possibleValues
 if(s.toChar = c) then
  doSomething()
 end if
Next c
```

Sorry, my VB is rusty, you can take the above as pseudocode.

Comment: That's actually quite an elegant solution and would be ingenious if it was neccessary; but it's not. I'll just use the case statement =p I will give you an upvote though

Answer (score 1):

How about creating using some sort of lookup?

```
Dim arrValue = "Hello"
Dim matches = "01234567890abcedf".ToCharArray()

For i = 0 To arrValue.Length

    If matches.Contains(arrValue(arrValue.Length - i)) Then
        '  Do work here
    End If
Next
```

...And yes, this really looks like a job for Regex, but this is yet another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a SWITCH Statement ?

```
switch(arrValue(strLength - i))
{
case 0:
"do this";
break;

case 1:
"do this";
break;
}
```

Comment: But not for that many cases, if all characters will trigger the same action.

Comment: You can add commas to include multiple conditions that you want to trigger the same action for.  See my edited post above :)

Comment: Well Mark, then do this. Store your 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,6 & 7 in an array (say M). Assign your arrValue(strLength - i) to a variable (Say X) . Check if X exists in M . Problem solved.